# Passing thread as argument in flask

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

I am creating a website using flask and this is my situation:
I have a really big script that i need to run on the server so if I just call the script with `subprocess.Popen` the server will time out. So what I want to do is make a thread , call the script with `Popen` in the thread and after the thread finishes to show the result. I want to check if the thread has finished with `is_alive` but i dont know how to pass it as an argument. This is my code so far:

(I am simplifing the example so no `Popen` just `time.sleep` )

```
 def funk():
      time.sleep(10)
      print ("Works")

  @app.route('/')
  def home():
      thread = Thread(target = funk)
      thread.start()
      return redirect('end',thread = thread)

  @app.route('/end')
  def end(thread):
      if thread.is_alive() == 0:
          return "Still working"
      else:
          return "Ended"
```

But i am getting an error :

> TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thread'

Does anybody know how to pass the thread as an argument?

I have an earlier version in which I had a global constant that I modified in the thread and asking in `end` if it has changed, that worked but that is a stupid solution.

Comment: You cannot pass a parameter by redirect function here. If you want to check the status of the thread, you may want to put the thread a global variable.

Comment: thank you, will try